# Expand list between multiple web parts

Tags: sharepoint-online

If I have a list with 100 items, is there a way I can create a web part page, insert 2 web parts, the one of the left to display items 1-50 and the one on the right to display items 51-100?

I just want to display the items on one page without the need to either scroll down or click the next button.

Edit: 
Sorry, forgot to add that I also want the list to be in ascending order by [last name] column. And, hopefully adjust each web parts to equally divide the list between the 2 whenever items are added or deleted.

The list only has 3 columns:

- ID
- Last Name
- First Name

Comment: Yes you can create two distinct view,  where you can add filter to include item 1-50 on one and 50-100 on another. Once Views are ready, add 2 list view web parts and and assign that view to it. That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create 2 Views, View A with the below filter condition :
[image]

And Create a Second View B with the below filter condition :
[image]

Now you can show these 2 views Side by Side Or One Down after another depending on the page layout you have created. This will help you achieve your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to display 100 items in 2 batches, in the first view you can display by limiting items to 50.**

[image]

**In the next view, you have to Add the filter condition to fetch next 50. Get the ID of the 50th item and replace in the filter condition as shown in the below image and limit the items to 50.**

[image]

Comment: I'll give this a try. But I also want to keep the list in ascending order. What happens if a new item is added (i.e. starts with "A") and the ID number is 101?

Comment: The split works best with one column which is ID. If you want an alphabet fashion you can create multiple views without limiting items count. The example View 1 (A-E): Title starts with A or Title Starts with B or Title Starts with C or Title Starts with D or Title Starts with E. View 2 (F-K) like this. To avoid scrolling add a Item Limit 50 which I am thinking max documents in your case.

Comment: I was hoping something more dynamic to equally split the contents between 2 web parts.  But since I want to maintain the sort order by last name, I ended up creating 3 different views/webparts (A-I), (J-Q), and (R-Z).

Comment: Yes. That is the only way you can split into multiple views.